# Opposite of "straight talk"

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests, antonyms

What is the opposite for the *straight talk* idiom? How do I best call the activity when someone makes a very long preamble before he says what he wants?

Comment: In my experience, "straight talk" can also imply a high level of honesty.  In that case, the opposite could include gossip, flattery, and deceit.

Comment: @oosterwal "Straight talk" does mean speaking with a high level of honesty -- rather than "coming straight to the point" as OP implies.

Comment: My first thought was ‘gay talk’, but I don’t suppose that’s quite what you’re looking for here …

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the noble spirit of one immortal oratorm when he so colorfully advised our hero . . .

> This business is well ended.
>   My liege, and madam, to expostulate
>   What majesty should be, what duty is,
>   Why day is day, night night, and time is time,
>   Were nothing but to waste night, day and time.
>   Therefore, since brevity is the soul of wit,
>   And tediousness the limbs and outward flourishes,
>   I will be brief: your noble son is mad:
>   Mad call I it; for, to define true madness,
>   What is’t but to be nothing else but mad?
>   But let that go.

. . . I can myself do little less than recommend vigorously not timorously, for *timor* no more profits a man than it does a mouse or a moth, any of the following fine and splendid formulations of art:

- *chatty*
- *circuitous*
- *circumlocutory*
- *desultory*
- *diffuse*
- *digressive*
- *discursive*
- *evasive*
- *gabby*
- *garrulous*
- *long-winded*
- *loquacious*
- *maundering*
- *meandering*
- *palaverous*
- *prolix*
- *rambling*
- *talkative*
- *turgid*
- *vague*
- *verbose*
- *waffling*
- *windy*
- *wordy*

and of course, my personal favorite word for vexing prattlers wont to sacrifice wit’s soul on the altar of florid flourish:

## •  *Polonian*

Comment: I like `long-winded` and `rambling`.

Comment: @oosterwal Many people do. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are actually talking about someone who waffles on long-windedly before getting to the point (rather than someone who doesn’t say things straight out and honestly, which is how I too would understand ‘straight talk’), the first idiom that comes to mind is ***beating around the bush***.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest *pussyfoot* for the specific use you mentioned. In other uses, I might say an antonym for *straight talk* would be *euphemism* or the vulgar *B.S.* even.

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of a familiar and straightforward idiom would be a strange and impenetrable circumlocution. I suggest "obfuscatory tergiversation."

Comment: Had to look up tergiversation, but it's a good word.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of *straight* is *crooked* (the adjective /'krʊkəd/, not the past participle /krʊkt/).

The opposite of *talking* is *thinking*, in the sense that what one says may not represent what one thinks. Particularly when the topic is lying.

So I'd say the opposite of ***straight talk*** would be ***crooked thinking***.

Comment: The opposite of talking, surely, is just not talking. So **crooked silence** is even more of a direct opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Last year the question [Word for a person who talks without content](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/242760/26083)
was closed as a duplicate of this one. 
While I believe that my answer works for *this* question,
I believe that it works even better for [that one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/242760/26083). 
The answer is ***double-talk***.

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-talk):
>
> - language that appears to be earnest and meaningful
>     but in fact is a mixture of sense and nonsense
>
>   inflated, involved, and often deliberately ambiguous language
>
>   language that uses many words but has very little meaning
>
> [English Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/double-talk):
>
>   another term for
>   *[doublespeak](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/doublespeak)*
>
>   ***[doublespeak](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/doublespeak)***
>   :
>
>   Deliberately euphemistic, ambiguous, or obscure language.
>   *‘the art of political doublespeak’*
>
> [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/double-talk):
>
>   empty, deceptive, or ambiguous talk, esp by politicians
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/double-talk):
>
>   a way of saying things that makes it impossible for people to understand,
>     used by people in official positions when they want to hide the truth
>
> [grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/doublespeakterm.htm) discusses *doublespeak*:
>
> Doublespeak is language that's intended to deceive or confuse people.  …
>   
> Doublespeak may take the form of euphemisms,
>   unsupported generalizations, or deliberate ambiguity. 
>   Contrast with  *[plain English](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Plain-English-term.htm)*.
>
> William Lutz has defined doublespeak as
>   “language which pretends to communicate but doesn’t.”

The [grammar.about.com page referenced above](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/doublespeakterm.htm)
lists many other terms, phrases, and references
that relate to these questions, such as

- [bureaucratese](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/bureaucrateseterm.htm)
- [drivel](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/George-Carlins-Essential-Drivel.htm)
- [weasel words](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/What-Are-Weasel-Words.htm)

---

#### Amusing Contemporary Notes:

- The reference for [drivel](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/George-Carlins-Essential-Drivel.htm) is a link to an article
  on [George Carlin’s Essential Drivel](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/George-Carlins-Essential-Drivel.htm),
  which, amidst a long string of
  “superfluous redundant pleonastic tautologies,”
  mentions “over-exaggerating,”
  which was recently popularized by an Olympic athlete.
- [Why You’ll Never Be Told, “You’re Fired”](http://grammar.about.com/od/words/fl/51-Euphemisms-for-Youre-Fired.htm) links to a page
  that leads with a photograph of Donald Trump.