# Opposite of "verbose"

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

One definition of [*verbose*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/verbose) states:

> characterized by the use of many or **too many** words; wordy: a verbose report.

Some (including the above link) suggest that the opposite is [*concise*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concise) or [*laconic*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/laconic), however both mean *covering much* in few words.

Is there an opposite of *verbose* which means the use of *too few* words?

Here's [a blog post](http://www.socialpmchick.com/2010/04/23/will-the-real-opposite-of-verbose-please-stand-up/) about this, although it doesn't offer an alternative.

Comment: [Antonyms of _verbose_](http://thesaurus.com/browse/verbose?s=b). The best two for your question are _terse_ and _curt_, although the latter had a decided negative connotation of rudeness.

Comment: You've shot yourself in the foot - giving one sense for _laconic_ (and not the one mentioned first) from one dictionary. Here are other statements from dictionaries:  concise to the point of seeming rude or mysterious // (of a person's speech) using few words; terse

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True, but I don't think either suggest "too few"...?

Comment: @hayden Certainly *pauciloquent* has “too few words” built right into it.  Otherwise, just use multiple words.

Comment: I would consider **succinct** the opposite, but it doesn't convey having too *few* words - it has just enough *(which is much less than most people would use)*.

Comment: @hayden: For laconic, _concise to the point of seeming rude_ suggests 'using too few words'; as Bill says, _curt_ has this connotation also. If you mean 'too few words' from a perspective of clarity or roundedness, such an article say might be termed _overbrief_, _thin_ or _flimsy_.

Comment: One-word answers should be allowed, just for this question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth probably has the best answer with 'overly brief'.   Was going to mention 'terse' and 'curt', as others have, but neither necessarily means *too* few.   Then again, verbose doen't necessarily mean *too* many; I would think of terse as being the opposite of verbose.

Comment: wouldn't it be better, if opposite is as simple as, 'verbish'?

Comment: depending on how the rest of your sentence is structured, `sparse` worked for me as an antonym

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Terse](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199621): sparing in the use of words; abrupt - "a terse statement". The current use according to [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199621) is "Freed from verbal redundancy; neatly concise; compact and pithy in style or language."

Comment: I’d argue that for the purpose of this question “terse” is almost a synonym to “concise”, neither means “too few words to express the content”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I agree with you, it doesn't fit the "too few" requirement... It is more "as little as possible". Then the right antonym may be simply : `short` ? or `shorted` ?

Comment: @Olivier I actually think “curt” is the perfect antonym.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: it does indeed seem to fit nicely too. +1 to you.

Comment: I'd argue that "concise" is using few words, while "terse" is using "too few" words, as it is often used when being annoyed and therefore reluctant to speak. The "too few" is also reflected in the slightly negative connotation of "terse", as opposed to "concise", which is neutral unless sarcasm is involved.

Comment: +1. It should also be noted that in hacker jargon, verbose and terse are pretty much perfect antonyms. Many linux command line tools have "terse" modes vs. "verbose" modes (to indicate how much status information they should output as they perform their operation).

Answer (score 13):

How about:

**succinct**

suc·cinct  [suhk-singkt]

1. expressed in few words; concise; terse.

2. characterized by conciseness or verbal brevity.

3. compressed into a small area, scope, or compass.

From http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/succinct

Comment: +1, because it was my first thought... but no, it does not mean "too few" words

Comment: I guess I should have posted this as an answer instead of a comment...

Answer (score 12):

If a simple ***curt*** is too short for you, there’s always [***pauciloquent***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/139014), meaning with few words.  All *pauciloquies* are by definition *laconic* ones rather than [*Polonian*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96689) speeches.

Whether that implies that not **enough** words were curtly spoken by the [tight-lipped orator](http://thesaurus.com/browse/terse), or just the right number, is open to individual interpretation.

Comment: Whether or not it is what he wants, thank you for mentioning pauciloquent.   Good word.   Not sure if it covers '*too* few', though ...

Comment: @hunter2 It does. *Pauci-* specifically means “few” and *-loquent* means “speaking”. See also *eloquent,  grandiloquent,  magniloquent, melliloquent, coproloquent*.

Comment: @tchrist: great word, but still "few speaking" doesn't induce "too few". "too few" indicates words are missing to be correct/complete. I propose: `short` or `shorted`

Comment: Yes, I understand that it covers "few words", but as Olivier says, that doesn't strictly mean *too* few.   I do recognize that 'paucity' generally suggests not just 'few', but 'too few', although the defn you linked doesn't suggest 'the *too*' - hence "not sure".   As I said in a comment to the question, 'verbose' doesn't strictly mean *too* many, either, so ... IDK.

Comment: Also, does *coproloquent* mean what I think it does?   Wow ...

Comment: @tchrist, much to my chagrin, I can't find a reference/citation for 'coproloquent' ...

Answer (score 7):

Someone who is ***"taciturn"*** speaks little.

> Definition from the Free Online Dictionary: habitually silent,
>   reserved, or uncommunicative; not inclined to conversation [from Latin
>   taciturnus, from tacitus silent, from tacēre to be silent]

A more colorful way to describe a person who uses too few words is ***"tight-lipped"***, though this can mean, depending on context, that someone is not *willing* to speak, as if they are keeping a secret.

Answer (score 5):

I always liked the word ***laconic***.

> using or involving the use of a minimum of words : concise to the point of seeming rude or mysterious - [Definition from Miriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laconic)

Although I don't get enough opportunities to use it. In the sense of "*consise to the point of seeming rude*", it implies the use of *too few* words.

Comment: +1 I particularly like the fact that this ultimately derives from Sparta - see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/laconic .

Answer (score 4):

yet another option would be [brief](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brief)

```
brief 
adj. brief·er, brief·est
1. Short in time, duration, length, or extent.
2. Succinct; concise: a brief account of the incident.
3. Curt; abrupt.
n.
1. A short, succinct statement.
2. A condensation or an abstract of a larger document or series of documents.
```

particularly the 3rd definition as an adjective seems to fit

Comment: +1 because _brief_ is also the opposite of _verbose_ in Zork.

Answer (score 3):

I am not English so be kind. But from French, I would say *succinct* would be my first choice, *brief, concise, expressed with very little words*.

I don't think you can find the perfect opposite for "too many words", because with "not enough words" you can't really express anything but meaningless sentences.  Maybe with "an explanation being too brief"

Also we have *condensé* in French, don't know if you can say *condensed* in English, as something with a higher density.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a regularly-used, modern English word that means "too few words to convey meaning". There is, however, one word that *does* mean that, albeit as a rarely-used meaning in modern use.

That word is ***elliptic***. *Elliptic*, [as Merriam-Webster defines it](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elliptic), has two principal meanings:

> 1: of, relating to, or shaped like an ellipse
>
> 2
>
> a : of, relating to, or marked by ellipsis or an ellipsis
>
> b (1) : of, relating to, or marked by extreme economy of speech or writing (2) : of or relating to deliberate obscurity (as of literary or conversational style)

It definitely has the sense of concision and omission of important detail. "An elliptic report", to my mind, would be one that was not thorough or complete, perhaps leaping to conclusions without sufficient justification, etc.

With all that said, however, for most people *elliptical* would refer to the shape.

Answer (score 2):

These all depend on context, but if I wanted to express that someone used too few words to get a concept across, I might use the following to describe their delivery:

- bare
- lacking
- wanting
- needing
- incomplete

These are perhaps not antonyms to "verbose" specifically, but I hope they help.

Answer (score 0):

How about [brevity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brevity) ?

Cambridge Dictionary describes it as "using only a few words or lasting only a short time".

Also, [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brevity)

```
brevity [ˈbrɛvɪtɪ]
n pl -ties
1. conciseness of expression; lack of verbosity
2. a short duration; brief time
[from Latin brevitās shortness, from brevis brief]
```

Comment: *Brevity* is not an adjective.

Comment: Would `bereft` work in-place for an adjective?

Answer (score -1):

*Pithy* and *meaty* can be added to the list.