# What are some words that mean "Few in words but spoken intelligently"?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to think of some words that would describe one as being able to speak little but speak intelligently. "Economical" seems good, but I feel as though there are more accurate words.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Succinct and to the point

Comment: -1  no research indicated

Comment: See e.g. the answers to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111606/opposite-of-verbose (a different but overlapping question)

Answer (score 1):

If I were describing such a person, I would probably say,

### “She speaks simply but eloquently.”

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/eloquent

Eloquently |Definition of Eloquently by Vocabulary.com Dictionary

*When something is beautifully, gorgeously, perfectly said (or written), it is eloquent.*

---

Or, perhaps,

### “He is a man of few words, but when he speaks, he speaks with conviction.”

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conviction

Conviction | Definition of Conviction by Merriam-Webster

*a strong belief or opinion. : the feeling of being sure that what you believe or say is true.*