# Looking for a better phrase than "caught up in the minutiae"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

Although it is very appropriate for the appraisal that I am writing, it has become overused in our workplace.  Any suggestions for alternate wording is appreciated.

Comment: Possible link: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94774/word-to-describe-when-someone-describes-something-in-too-much-detail

Comment: Another possibility: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/408391/24489

Comment: Also [Phrase for focusing on unimportant details](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43237/phrase-for-focusing-on-unimportant-details).

Comment: I agree with *getting bogged down in the details*, which was already suggested as an answer at [Idiom for explaining something too thoroughly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408391/idiom-for-explaining-something-too-thoroughly)

Comment: I like "lost in the weeds".

Answer (score 0):

A common alternative is "can't see the forest for the trees."  That may be a bit casual for your purpose if you're in a technical field.